ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC : "System.NullReferenceException" error
I have the following .cshtml view I'm calling to both display my "Create" and "Update" form.
All works fine till I decided to introduce the "if" condition to change both the title and the submit button captions of the form in order to differentiate between the "Create" and the "Update" action that is sent to my controller.
In the "if" statement, when I type the word "Model." I can see the intellisense popping up my Model's properties list that I can choose from.
When I build my project, everything looks fine.
But when I hit my submit button to show the "Create" form, I get the following error.
But when I hit my submit button to show the "Update" form, I don't get any error.
I really don't see the error or omission inside my code:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

(See screenshot)
@model ProfessionVM

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4 row">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">@(Model.NoProfession != 0 ? "MODIFIER" : "AJOUTER") UNE PROFESSION</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <input asp-for="NoProfession" class="form-control" hidden />
        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="NomProfession"> </label>
            <input asp-for="NomProfession" class="form-control" id="txtNomProf"
                   onblur="validateInput(this)" />
            <span asp-validation-for="NomProfession" class="text-bg-danger"> </span>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="Inactif"> </label>
            <input asp-for="Inactif" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="chkInActif" checked
                   onblur="validateInput(this)" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="mb-3 row p-1">
            <label asp-for="RemProfession"> </label>
            <textarea asp-for="RemProfession" class="form-control" rows="5" id="txtRemProf"
                      onblur="validateInput(this)">RAS</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                @if (Model.NoProfession != 0 || Model.NoProfession != null)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="boutModif" disabled>Modifier</button>
                }
                else
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="boutModif" disabled>Ajouter</button>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                <a asp-controller="Administrateur" asp-action="list_Professions" class="btn btn-dark border form-control">
                    Retour à la liste des professions
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<input type="text" id="verifValNomProfession" value="0" hidden />
<input type="text" id="verifValRemProfession" value="0" hidden />
<input type="text" id="verifChkInActif" value="0" hidden />

@section Scripts {
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            $(':disabled').each(function(e) {
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            })
        });

        function validateInput(input) {
            switch (input.id) {
                case "txtNomProf":
                case "txtRemProf":
                    var defaultVal = input.defaultValue.toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp(/\r?\n|\r/g), " "); 
                    var currentVal = input.value.toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp(/\r?\n|\r/g), " "); 
                    var c = document.getElementById("verifChkInActif"); 
                    var g = document.getElementById("boutModif");

                    if (input.id == "txtNomProf") {
                        var b = document.getElementById("verifValNomProfession");
                        var d = document.getElementById("verifValRemProfession");
                    } else { 
                        var b = document.getElementById("verifValRemProfession");
                        var d = document.getElementById("verifValNomProfession");
                    };
                    (defaultVal == currentVal) ? b.value = "0" : b.value = "1";

                    (parseInt(b.value) + parseInt(c.value) + parseInt(d.value) > 0) ? g.disabled = false : g.disabled = true;
                    break;
                case "chkInActif":
                    console.log("C'est bon!");
                    var x = input.defaultChecked;
                    var z = input.checked;
                    var b = document.getElementById("verifChkInActif");
                    var c = document.getElementById("verifValNomProfession"); 
                    var d = document.getElementById("verifValRemProfession"); 
                    var g = document.getElementById("boutModif"); 

                    (x.toString() == z.toString()) ? b.value = "0" : b.value = "1";

                    (parseInt(b.value) + parseInt(c.value) + parseInt(d.value) > 0) ? g.disabled = false : g.disabled = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    alert ("Il y a gbangban!");
            };
        };
    </script>
}



If that NoProfession value is null-able then your #null check or handling has to be done before any comparison. For instance with this check:
@if (Model.NoProfession != 0 || Model.NoProfession != null)

should be:
@if ( Model.NoProfession != null || Model.NoProfession != 0 )

When .Net evaluates a conditional statement it goes left to right and "fails fast" so the first opportunity to match a condition and it will exit. Checking a value against #null will raise an exception so check for the #null first.
Alternatively to simplify the expression:
@if (Model?.NoProfession ?? 0 != 0)

This says if the NoProfession is #null, treat it as a "0".
If you are still getting NullReferenceExceptions raised then be sure that when you are rendering the View from the controller or other code that you are populating and passing a Model. For instance if you have code that returns just View() without populating a ProfessionVM instance then the expected Model will be #null at runtime. For Razor code you can set breakpoints in the .cshtml on any "@" code block and inspect the Model to ensure it's set and that all expected properties are available.

Thanks,
That explanation helped me fix it.
